# Qual a forma mais simples de recuperar determinados elementos de um XML com Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Tenho o seguinte `XML`:

```
<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <documentos/>
        <livros>
            <livro nome="Nome1"/>
            <livro nome="Nome2"/>
        </livros>
    </cliente>
    <cliente>
        <documentos/>
        <livros>
            <livro nome="Nome1"/>
            <livro nome="Nome3"/>
        </livros>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

Como faço para recuperar uma lista com todos os livros distintos dele utilizando `Linq`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
var s = @"<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <documentos/>
        <livros>
            <livro nome=""Nome1""/>
            <livro nome=""Nome2""/>
        </livros>
    </cliente>
    <cliente>
        <documentos/>
        <livros>
            <livro nome=""Nome1""/>
            <livro nome=""Nome3""/>
        </livros>
    </cliente>
</clientes>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(s);

var livros = doc.Descendants("livro")
                .Select(_=>_.Attribute("nome").Value)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

/* 'livros' contem:

Nome1
Nome2
Nome3

*/
```

Comment: Gostei da sua implementação, mas não seria o caso de chamar o método `Attribute` ao invés do `Attributes` e depois o `First`?

Comment: Muito bem observado.  Alterei o exemplo conforme o sugerido.

Comment: Ficou bem simples, "uma linha só".

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
var clientes = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"C:\TEMP\arquivo.xml");

var livros = new List<string>();

foreach (var cliente in clientes.Root.Elements())
{
    foreach (var livrosEdocumentos in cliente.Elements())
    {
        if (livrosEdocumentos.Name == "livros")
        {
            foreach (var livro in livrosEdocumentos.Elements())
            {
                var lv = (from l in livros
                          where l == livro.FirstAttribute.Value
                          select l).FirstOrDefault();

                if (lv == null)
                {
                    livros.Add(livro.FirstAttribute.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coloque seu XML no 'arquivo.xml'.

O resultado distinto retornará na lista `List<>` `livros`